# Is there really no way for Australian citizens to return home from India right now legally?

Tags: legal, india, australia, covid-19, australian-citizens

I just read that Australia has passed a law that makes it illegal for citizens to return home from India.

Is there absolutely no way to do it? Can't the embassy in New Delhi assist in some way? I assumed the government would arrange some kind of quarantine  with rigorous testing in approved and monitored facilities before and after a chartered government flight to get citizens home or something.

But it seems they won't do that? Australian citizens are simply not allowed to return home, even if they found a way? I always assumed that a state can never reject its own citizens, which is why I assumed Australia would go for the forced quarantine option in government facilities.

Comment: A state wont reject its own citizen, which is why this is a criminal matter with fines and jail time rather than deportation - a state can still penalise its citizens for an action its made illegal, just dont conflate that with any rejection of entry.  Australia doesnt want to deal with the influx that allowing arrivals from india would entail.

Comment: Have you tried to contact the embassy?

Comment: Rh e issue with India is just another facet of Aussie expats having very little ability to return home over the past year.

Comment: What's your goal? Travel freely, or avoid getting COVID?  As a practical issue, you may be better off "holing up" isolating in India and waiting it out... than running all over the place talking to 100 different people about lining up an expatriation flight, actually visiting the airport and the flight, etc.  You don't get COVID from statistics, you get it from interacting with other humans.  Isolate like Heisenberg in New Hampshire and you cannot get COVID. Amazon delivers in India.

Comment: @Moo I don't know the particulars about the travel ban from India to Australia, but it seems to be a common practice that if one is not allowed to travel from country A to country B, they cannot board the flight in the first place.

Comment: @Jake as we have found in NZ with the deliberate breach of the Tasman bubble by a traveller who left Perth while under lockdown, flew to Sydney and then to NZ, it heavily depends on the traveller not being deceptive.  Punishment for infringements mean that people think twice about travelling from country A to country C and then to country B to circumvent a travel ban between countries A and B.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica their goal is probably to **go back home in a difficult time**, which is a very valid goal that does not warrant scolding. The fact that Australia has made headlines all over the world for punishing its citizens for trying to go back home supports my statement. And of course, staying in India carries a much higher risk of getting covid than going back home, so your comment does not really apply.

Comment: "And of course, staying in India carries a much higher risk of getting covid than going back home" - That is not correct. Staying (isolated) in India has lower risk *to you* then traveling in, through or from India, and poses a much, much lower risk to the rest of Australia.

Comment: @wimi I'm a NZer in NZ - and about to travel to Australia. It sounds from your comment that you did not read and/or follow HRM's comment. He makes a good case for it being safer to remain in India and to self isolate late than to attempt to negotiate the tortuous path home. Indian people processing can be a complex process in simple times (although I fared very well in my only time in India) - in attempting to leave India at present one would be required to run a gauntlet that almost certainly made the risk far higher than sheltering in place.

Comment: @wimi for interest - you may not realise the CV19 situation in NZ and Australia. NZ is CV19 free except for incoming cases and Australia is much the same with occasional community bursts as incoming cases cause community problems. Passengers on a recent incoming flight from India were certified CV19 free and a large majority subsequently proved to have CV19. The situation in India at present is utterly dire and the risks to the whole populations in Australia and NZ warrant extreme measures if CV19 is not to be admitted. | For interest - where are you located?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon do you know whether AU is quarantining 100% of incoming travellers like NZ?

Comment: @user253751  As far as I am aware, yes  - 100% quarantine EXCEPT from NZ. We have an inter-country "travel bubble" between NZ and parts of Australia. This may change by the day. I'm due to travel to Oz May 15th return 28th. MAY not get to go and MAY not get to come back :-).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon worth noting that Australia never barred entry from the US, UK, Europe at the height of their outbreaks. I really think there's a racial component here, Australia simply doesn't consider non-white Australians to be on the same level as citizens. https://imgur.com/a/MsGES2l

Comment: @IvanMcA I'll start with the most egregious point. The cited graph is **relatively** meaningless. Absolute rate matters, where it is concentrated matters and how well it is able to be managed matters. Rate per million has some bearing but in isolation is immensely misleading. | The graph [here](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/worldwide-graphs/] shows what is happening in India. Very sadly. | [THese](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/?utm_campaign=homeAdUOA?Si#countries) per country pages give good insight, and the daily deaths and daily new cases ...

Comment: ... [here](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/india/) - which are generally believed to be significantly lower than actual due to the inability to keep up with wjhat is happening, show the recent increases in rate of infection and death. || (2) Yes, there are quite a few racist Australians. Less so in government proportionately - partially due to experience gained in recent decades in indigenous matters and partially because Australia is an immense multi racial melting pot. (NZ, where I live, is a smaller but as diverse one). Shortly before the full ban a planeload of  ...

Comment: ... people from India who had all been prechecked and certified covid-19 free proved to have the large majority CV19 infected. When the status of the nation depends very greatly on control at the border the current rampant increases and uncontrollable situation in India make the current actions undesirable but wise. Sadly. Note that no Australian citizen can currently travel from India to Australia.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon a planeload of Australians, you mean, who had recently been to India. This is what I mean, the idea that they aren't even seen as properly Australian, you see them not as "Australians" but as "people from India".

Comment: I'm bountying this question not because I'm in need of this information, but because I don't want outdated info being provided in this post.

Comment: @IvanMcA  I just now saw your May 5th comment. I'm sorry of my comment came across in a manner that I had not intended or appeared to convey something which I sincerely hope was not my intention. I already do not recall the fine detail of the event but I do not think at the time that news reports made it clear that the people concerned were Australian citizens. I'm abouit certain that vthey did not identify their ethnicity but I imagine it was generally assumed (by me and others) that a majoritywere ethnically Indian. I do not claom that "race" does not influence my perceptions - I do ...

Comment: ... assert that as a Christian and memeber of humanity that I try to be aware as I can of both positive / negative / different influences and seek to behave & think in a manner which is as God would wish. (Invoking the "God card" would not usually be a good idea on an SE site but seems apposite here. I've visited 35 countries and would love to visit more. People vary widely in a range of ways - I seek as well as I may to see and consider them all as "children of God", just as I am. | Again: I regret if I failed to communicate clearly.

Comment: @IvanMcA I note that for all of those concerned who were Australian citizens the question is a far better one than otherwise. Looking again at the question I see that it makes it very clear that they are talking about Australian CITIZENS. I assume thatI had thatin mine when I commented - but maybe not. My comments about many people certified covid free turning up covid affected appearsto still be relevant. I do not know to what extent vthis applied or applies to people from other countries.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They can spend 14 days in another country and then return, but that becomes increasingly difficult with travel restrictions.

> Australian citizens are simply not allowed to return home, even if they found a way?

That's why the laws threatens with fines and jail terms. They will not be sent back if they somehow reach Australian soil.

> Is there absolutely no way to do it? Can't the embassy in New Delhi assist in some way? I assumed the government would arrange some kind of quarantine with rigorous testing in approved and monitored facilities before and after a chartered government flight to get citizens home or something.

I am not sure if you are asking if there is no way for the government to do it or the affected citizens and residents. For the government, it is sovereign and can decide to provide such facility or not, subject to possible consequences on its international reputations or internal approval. Why they choose one way or another is not a question suitable on Travel.SE.

For the affected citizens and residents, once the proposed measures take effect, it is not legally possible for them to return.

---

Additionally, even if the international law requires to different degrees that citizens have a right of return, it is not really enforceable unless the country incorporates the right in domestic law (e.g. Canada, even then it's subject to limitations, but at least the court would carefully examine the case), although in some cases other countries where the citizens of the country denying the right of return currently are may protest. [Australia apparently does not have a direct incorporation of a right to return in its constitution, though legal challenges on other grounds can take place but it is not clear and will take some time.](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-australia-56953052)

Plus, it doesn't prohibit countries making reentry very difficult or very expensive.

Comment: Oh, ok, I see. So if they found some way to leave India, then spent 14 days in another country, then somehow managed to get to Australia, then they wouldn't be prosecuted.

Comment: Note that prohibiting citizens returning home isn't entirely new; several European countries have tried the same with people accused of travelling to Syria to join or even fight for Islamic State.

Comment: The lack of a quarantine system is pretty stupid, but the people who complain about this want the border to be completely open, which is also pretty stupid.

Comment: @user253751 I am not understanding your comment.  I thought that Australia did have a quarantine system.  (Not Australian so I am probably mistaken.)

Comment: @Emory Australia does have a quarantine system, but it is not open to people travelling from india, only from countries with lower Covid levels

Comment: `The lack of a quarantine system is pretty stupid` There _is_ a quarantine system (https://www.health.gov.au/news/health-alerts/novel-coronavirus-2019-ncov-health-alert/coronavirus-covid-19-restrictions/coronavirus-covid-19-advice-for-international-travellers) - they just want to keep it at a manageable level. Australia has for the last 10 months or so freaked out over even 20 cases in a given state, so this latest reaction is reasonably consistent with that. Obviously if you did find your way back they would put you in quarantine.

Comment: There is a quarantine system, yes, however, there have been a number of problems relating to cases [leaving quarantine](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2021-04-23/perth-plunged-into-three-day-lockdown-after-hotel-covid/100091188), generally spreading to security guards or other people in quarantine, so, as far as i understand, they are just trying to hand the risks associated with quarantining over to other countries

Comment: @BobKerman That is likely part of the motivation - yes. ;)

Comment: @gerrit Not just tried -- succeeded too.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamima_Begum

Comment: @mjwills The problem is people are not allowed to return even if they can find a quarantine slot. (Are AU doing quarantine slots like NZ is?)

Comment: That is correct @user253751. The point I am making is that some of the earlier comments implied there is a lack of quarantine system, which is false. Once you arrive in the country, you will be quarantined. So there is a quarantine system. I mean, there is a massive fine if you manage to somehow arrive from India - true (as the answer says `They will not be sent back if they somehow reach Australian soil.`). ;) `Are AU doing quarantine slots like NZ is?` The main mechanism, by my understanding, is attempting to limit the number of incoming passengers (from any source).

Comment: afaik (as a NZer) Australia has a 100% quarantine system (except for people from NZ). NZ similarly.